# Real & accurate memory usage statistics (top)?

Tags: ram

Need accurate memory usage statistics to figure out what size matrix I can work with without choking the RAM on this laptop. ;)

I am using `top` to figure out how much memory an app I'm working on is using.
The issue is that I do not understand the information that is presented?

Specifically, it says I'm using ~6.5gigs out of 7.8 gigs, which would be about 85% of all memory. The column that's called `%MEM` says the process is using 15.0 and chrome is using another ~5.4. I don't understand what used is and what `%MEM` is.

```
top - 11:15:04 up  1:15,  4 users,  load average: 2.12, 1.52, 1.18
Tasks: 230 total,   2 running, 228 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 27.6 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 72.1 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   7861188 total,  6516808 used,  1344380 free,    95792 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  3697392 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                  
 2753 arthur    20   0 1320032 1.121g   6732 R 100.0 15.0  58:35.05 svd_all_ri_clus                                                                                                                          
 3481 arthur    20   0 1261924 222324  22736 S   4.0  2.8   0:08.09 chrome                                                                                                                                   
 3512 arthur    20   0 1232108 204356  22396 S   2.3  2.6   0:06.60 chrome                                                                                                                                   
 2461 arthur    20   0  666052  25800  13436 S   1.7  0.3   0:06.95 gnome-terminal                                                                                                                           
 1343 root      20   0  393284  83852  74748 S   1.3  1.1   0:11.93 Xorg                                                                                                                                     
 2208 arthur    20   0 1332004 101584  32700 S   0.7  1.3   0:18.16 compiz                                                                                                                                   
 3345 arthur    20   0 1506568 124560  59936 S   0.7  1.6   0:10.73 chrome                                                                                                                                   
 3411 arthur    20   0  785080 108416  19364 S   0.7  1.4   0:06.34 chrome                                                                                                                                   
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.19 rcuos/2                                                                                                                                  
 1177 root      20   0   30608   2752   2144 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.12 wpa_supplicant                                                                                                                           
 1937 arthur    20   0  361956   4328   2884 S   0.3  0.1   0:02.93 ibus-daemon                                                                                                                              
 2007 arthur    20   0  480028  15864  10876 S   0.3  0.2   0:00.88 ibus-ui-gtk3                                                                                                                             
 3047 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.26 kworker/u16:0
```

Just in case someone says read the man page, I already did (skimmed through it).
Does not appear to explain the difference between "used" and the sum total of what is listed under `%MEM`.

```
 2c. MEMORY Usage
       This portion consists of two lines which  may  express  values  in  kibibytes  (KiB)  through
       exbibytes (EiB) depending on the scaling factor enforced with the 'E' interactive command.

       Line 1 reflects physical memory, classified as:
           total, used, free and buffers

       Line 2 reflects mostly virtual memory, classified as:
           total, used, free and cached (which is physical memory)

       This table may help in interpreting the scaled values displayed:
           KiB = kibibyte = 1024 bytes
           MiB = mebibyte = 1024 KiB = 1,048,576 bytes
           GiB = gibibyte = 1024 MiB = 1,073,741,824 bytes
           TiB = tebibyte = 1024 GiB = 1,099,511,627,776 bytes
           PiB = pebibyte = 1024 TiB = 1,125,899,906,842,624 bytes
           EiB = exbibyte = 1024 PiB = 1,152,921,504,606,846,976 bytes

3. FIELDS / Columns
   3a. DESCRIPTIONS of Fields
       Listed  below  are  top's available process fields (columns).  They are shown in strict ascii
       alphabetical order.  You may customize their position and whether or not they are displayable
       with the 'f' or 'F' (Fields Management) interactive commands.

       Any  field  is selectable as the sort field, and you control whether they are sorted high-to-
       low or low-to-high.  For additional information on sort provisions see topic  4c.  TASK  AREA
       Commands, SORTING.

       The  fields  related  to  physical memory or virtual memory reference '(KiB)' as the default,
       unsuffixed display mode.  Such fields can, however, be scaled differently via the 'e'  inter‐
       active command.

        1. %CPU  --  CPU Usage
           The  task's  share  of  the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a
           percentage of total CPU time.

           In a true SMP environment, if a process is multi-threaded and top  is  not  operating  in
           Threads  mode,  amounts  greater than 100% may be reported.  You toggle Threads mode with
           the 'H' interactive command.

           Also for multi-processor environments, if  'Irix  mode'  is  Off,  top  will  operate  in
           'Solaris mode' where a task's cpu usage will be divided by the total number of CPUs.  You
           toggle 'Irix/Solaris' modes with the 'I' interactive command.

        2. %MEM  --  Memory Usage (RES)
           A task's currently used share of available physical memory.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `gnome-system-monitor` [image: gnome-system-monitor showing ram per program]
It shows the number of amount RAM used

Comment: Looks good but how do I see how much is really left?

Comment: I don't understant, sorry for my english.  You want to know how many ram is avaliable? `free -m `show to you free memory in mbytes. Or in gnome-system-monitor - second tab shows statistics from your RAM and CPU uses. It's useful?

Comment: I checked and the numbers add up. It appears to be sufficiently accurate for my purpose.